# How to save open/closed folds in vim with mksession?

Tags: vim

### Premise

I use

```
:mksession s.vim
```

to save my current session, and it does. Except for folds I opened or closed during it.

### Question

What should I do to enable that?

### Settings

I use the following fold settings in my `vimrc`

```
set foldcolumn=4
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested it, but I think that `:set sessionoptions+=folds` will do exactly what you want.

```
:help 'sessionoptions'
:help :mksession
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [mkview](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mkview) and [loadview](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:loadview).

In my `.vimrc`, from [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_views_automatic):

`" view
set viewdir=$HOME/.vim_view//
au BufWritePost,BufLeave,WinLeave ?* mkview " for tabs
au BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview`

Comment: So I don't have a default `vim` option?

Comment: I have some autocommands set up to automatically `mkview` and `loadview`. (See edit above.)

Comment: I believe the question is about fold persistence in sessions, not views.